# Deploy database to web hosting MVC4 - VS 2012 Express for Web

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, web-hosting, web-deployment

I've created a small website and now want to deploy it to web hosting **www.citynetwork.se**. I've successfully deployed the MVC4 code developed using .Net 4.0 framework. The connection string I'm using currently for localhost is;

```
<add name="EventtavlanContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=Eventtavlan1;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\Eventtavlan1" />
```

It works perfect at localhost but how should I deploy the database to the web hosting?

1. As my web hosting provides support for MySQL and MS SQL so should I
   create a new database on web hosting and create/deploy the schema
   only? How would I do that?
2. Should I include the database from App_Data folder while
   publishing from VS 2012 to the web hosting and change the connection
   string only? What would be the new connection string then?
3. Or is there any other way of deploying the database? Can somebody guide me
   with the easiest way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, create a new MS SQL database at the hosting provider. If you want to deploy the schema you can do that easily from Visual Studio using the dbDacFx provider. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394698.aspx#dbdacfx .
2. No, don't include the .mdf in App_Data.  You can't use a LocalDB database when running in IIS. When you create the database at the hosting provider they should provide the connection string.
3. Easiest way if you only want to deploy schema is dbDacFx provider as I mention in #1. That page I link to also mentions other options.  If you're using Code First, Migrations is a good way to deploy. See this tutorial:  http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/introduction